# I want a bootstrap cols css to be applied in laravel pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf

I am using Laravel inbuilt pdf to make PDF from the view but the view i made used bootstrap css but after converting the view in to pdf all bootstrap css is getting lost.
Below is my code

```
    $data = [
    'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('leadmanagement.jobcard_operation_view', $data);
    $pdf->SetProtection(['copy', 'print'], '', 'pass');
    return $pdf->stream('JOB CARD.pdf');
```

Below is some screen shot of how my view looks and how my pdf looks
[image]
 Image one is showing what type of view i actually need in my pdf

And How pdf Is Downloaded see below
[image]
Image 2nd Showing the view after pdf is being downloaded

Any help would be helpful

Comment: As of what [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) can support, try to use vanilla html as much as possible. CSS support isn't that fantastic too. Bootstrap cols floating, box-sizing etc may not work properly here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the bootstrap css into the pdf  as well.

Also make sure you are setting

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

In the document head. Another possibility is if you use elixir,  try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ltrim(elixir('assets/css/app.css'), '/') }}" />
```